# In python I want to generate single sentence output but instead i am having out put like ('harsh', 'ate', 'bread')

Tags: python

I am not able to generate single line sentence in python.

I want to generate out put as `harsh ate bread`, but I am having out put like - `('harsh', 'ate', 'bread')`.

I also tried to copy paste source code from the tutorial, but I am still having the same results. Please help.

Just for reference I am trying to work out code of the python tutorial from the new Boston. (tutorial no. 16).

Source code is:

```
def x(name='harsh', action='ate', item='bread'):
    print(name, action, item)

x()
```

Comment: Which python version are you using?

Comment: `print name, action, item` produces your desired result in python2.7

Comment: If you are using Python2.something remove the parenthesis from the `print`. The code you are copying is Python3 most likely

Comment: I think i am using python 3 .But I am using free version of PyCharm (while in the tutorials he is using paid version of the software)could that make this error .

Answer (score 0):

Try this. You need to concatenate the variables

```
 def x(name='harsh', action='ate', item='bread'):
    print(name + " " + action +" "+ item)
```

Comment: this is better `print(str(name)+ " " + str(action) + " " + str(item))`.

Answer (score 0):

`print (' '.join([name, action, item]))`

Comment: the other answer will work as well, but this does not require manually concatenating every space

Answer (score 0):

For python 3, this should work:
    **print (" ".join([name, action, item]))**